# Хранение личной информации пользователя. PHP

Tags: php, mysql

### Как хранить дополнительную информацию о пользователе?

---

**НЕ** `login, email` і т.д., **А** например: *Мои увлечения, Мой любимый сериал, Статус пользователя (Пример:"У меня отличное настроение!"), дату рождения, город, страну.*

Я бы мог сделать это все в одной таблице `users`, но не считаю это правильным тоном с разных точек зрения.

*Я не понимаю*, например, если у меня будет очень много таких полей *(мои увлечения, мои любимые сериалы..)*, то как мне быть в этом случаи? Просто делать много полей?

```
 id_user | Мой любый случай в жизни          | ... | ... | ... | 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------  
       1 | Однажды я написал "hello, world!" | ... | ... | ... |
```

---

**В общем, кроме вопроса выше, как мне объединить такие таблицы?**

Comment: Зачем вы пересоздали этот вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого обычно делаются вертикальные таблицы. Структура у них такая:

```
table (id, key, value)
```

При необходимости, их связывают с различными сущностями - можно сделать так:

```
table (id, user_id, key, value)
```

Также key можно вынести в отдельную таблицу, чтобы пользователи могли юзать уже существующие ключи. Т.е.:

```
key (id, title)
table (id, user_id, key_id, value)
```

В итоге получается такие таблицы:

```
Table: 
id | user_id | key_id | value
1  | 1       | 1      | Все хорошо

Key:
id | title
1  | Статус
```

В SQL данные можно получить одним запросом, используя JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t (INNER, LEFT) JOIN key AS k WHERE k.id = t.key_id
```

P.S. Прочитай про нормализацию/денормализацию БД, а также про отношения один-ко-многим, многие-ко-многим

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от функционала данные также можно хранить сериализованных переменных.

К примеру делаешь объект пользователя, например $user->status="Отличное настроение", затем выполняешь serialize($user) и заносишь это в БД. Обратная операция выполняется через unserialize.

Также стоит посмотреть на JSON

Answer (score 0):

Я всегда начинаю с самого простого, надо делать как можно проще...конечно можно наколбасить таблиц, стильных связей и чтоб позапутанней, и чтоб при создании записи позабыть что у меня еще в 5ти таблицах надо создать чего-то там...

Довольно интересный способ хранения информации в БД, которая не участвует в WHERE запросе.

```
id | date      | login  | password | lname  | sname  | fname   | info
----------------------------------------------------------------------
int| timestamp | varchar| varchar  | varchar| varchar| varchar | BLOB
```

в поле info хранится обычный JSON:

```
{"serial":"Doctor Who", "music":"Альянс - На заре", "food":"Курица"}
```

Преимущества очевидны:

- Не нужны куча таблиц и связей
- Простые запросы на выборку
- JSON легко распарсить

Недостатки:

- Сложно и муторно сделать выборку, например, выбрать всех у кого
  любимый сериал такой-то.

Comment: Согласен, JSON тут очень кстати, если не нужно делать фильтрацию. А если нужно делать фильтрацию, насколько я помню, в MySQL с 5.7 есть фильтрация по JSON столбцам :)